# Let $R_2 = \{1, \rho_2 \} \subset D_4$. Show that $R_2$ is a normal subgroup of $D_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, dihedral-groups

> Let $R_2 = \{1, \rho_2 \} \subset D_4$. Show that $R_2$ is a normal subgroup of $D_4$.

I have the definition that a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is normal if $gH=Hg$ for all $g \in G$.

Now if $\rho’ \in D_4$, then $\rho’R_2= \{\rho’ \cdot 1, \rho’ \cdot \rho_2\}$.

Clearly $p’ \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot p’$, but I’m not sure about $\rho’ \cdot \rho_2  = \rho_2 \cdot \rho’ $. Looking at the multiplicative table it seems that $\rho_2 $ is commutative? Thus $\rho’R_2  =R_2 \rho’ $ which would make $R_2$ normal?

Comment: Is $\rho_2$ a rotation?

Comment: To you, is $D_4$ defined geometrically?

Comment: It would only be true if $\rho_2$ is a rotation by "2 vertexes" (180 degrees). In this case, it would commute with every other element, I think.

Comment: I given a table and told that it’s se symmetries of a square. So I assume it’s geometrically defined. @Shaun

Comment: $R_2$ is the center, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036649/to-finde-the-center-of-d-4), and hence a normal subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of proving it directly, like you are trying to do, we can use the first isomorphism theorem, which links normal subgroups to homomorphisms.

Define the map

$$\begin{align}
\varphi: D_4 &\to \Bbb Z_2^2,\\
\rho & \mapsto (1,0),\\
\sigma &\mapsto (0,1).
\end{align}$$

Here $\rho$ is the rotation of the square by $\pi/2$ radians and $\sigma$ is the flip about the vertical axis of symmetry.

Verify that $\varphi$ defines a homomorphism. (It is defined on a generating set of $D_4$, sending each element to the elements of a generating set of $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$. The way to think about this is to note that every element has the form either $\rho^n$ or $\rho^n\sigma$, so verify it for each of these elements.${}^\dagger$) Its kernel is $R_2$. Thus, by the first isomorphism theorem, $R_2\unlhd D_4$.

---

$\dagger$: I thank @user1729 for [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59073471#59073471).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The relation $rs=sr^{-1}$ is part of the definition for the dihedral groups - it should be all you need.

In your notation you seem to have $\rho$ for rotations and $\rho'$ for reflections. So what I've said means $\rho\rho'=\rho'\rho^{-1}$, note $\rho^{-1}$ is $\rho^3$.

Comment: The OP defines the dihedral group geometrically. They might not know what $r$ and $s$ are.